# GCM Sender ID not showing on Google API console

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-api-console

I'm trying to check API Server key of GCM on Google API console, but if I select the project and checking the credentials, it's showing me a different Sender ID and API Server Key than what I configured on client side(app).

And if I'm trying to access `https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:<Sender_ID>` it's showing **You don't have permission to perform the action on the selected resource** message to me.

Maybe someone accidentally regenerated the API Server key? I don't know the exact reason, but I'm still getting push notification if I configure my previous API Server key on server, that means previous API Server key is still active.

**My question is :** how do again I get to show my previous Sender ID (that is configured on app) and API Server key on console?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried things out on my end and was able to see the same Sender ID and *Legacy* Server Key in my Google API Console.

What baffles me is how are you receiving ***access denied*** for a project that you say is yours. If you don't have access, then it just means you're not authorized.

The Sender ID (aka Project ID) is permanent, while when a Server Key is re-generated (old one deleted first), the old key will be immediately invalidated.

There are two things you could do:

- Import your Project to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and view the Sender ID and (*Legacy*) Server Key in the *Cloud Messaging* Tab from the Project Settings.
- Or you could reach out to GCM Support by filling out [this form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support) to further check why you're receiving ***Access denied*** for a project that you own.

Comment: Actually I have 3 apps in my play store a/c. When I'm trying to import in Firebase it showing me option of other two apps and not showing the third one which I wants to import. And when I going through this link `https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support` it showing message **You don't have permission to perform the action on the selected resource**

Comment: It the account that you're unable to access a personal account or a work account?

Comment: I've added the screen shot in question

Comment: I'm not sure first time while creation of project the app was registered with work account or some other a/c but app is showing of console with different Sender ID and if I'm trying to import in Firebase it's not showing that app in Firebase console

Comment: Sorry I entered the wrong link in above comment, the actual link is `https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:<Sender_ID>`

Comment: If it's a work account, you should contact your Google Account Admin. There might be something that isn't enabled for you, which denies you access.